# Create a button that stays in the foreground even with the application on pause

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a small app. It's one of my first one, and I'm not that good at coding for the moment. I want to create a button that stay even if the app is in background from a notification action.

I don't really know how to do this and I don't want you to do the job, just help me get started.

```
if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action != null) {

            switch (action) {

                case ACTION_CLOSE:

                    stopSelf();
                    break;

                case ACTION_LOCK:

                    // Can we create a view that stay on screen from here?

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an undecorated JFrame, and add your button to it. Make sure they are the same size.
Then, set the JFrame's alwaysOnTop to true - so your JFrame will stay in the foreground of the screen - with your button.

```
    JButton b=new JButton();        
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    f.add(b);
    b.setSize(150,150);
    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(150,150);
    f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Comment: What is the android equivalent for this? It's not working on android studio and I don't find anything on Internet. Thanks for taking time.